# how to convert the latitude and longitudein to postal address

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

*how to convert the latitude and longitude in to postal address. i am not possible to use mapview to get geopoint.I wanted to convert latitude and longitude in address without use of mapview*

Comment: Take a look at this API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Not all lat/long can be converted to an address because they don't have a record on Google's db. But you can use it to find the nearest place within a given distance.

Comment: we are not able to use mapview to get geopont.then how can i get geo point and convert it in address or how can i directlly convert latitude and longitude in address

Answer (score 0):

This is called `Reverse Geocoding`, there are number of services that you can use including [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/) and [Bing](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx)

[See this article](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/06/21/7-free-geocoding-apis-google-bing-yahoo-and-mapquest/) for free Geocoding services

Answer (score 0):

Android has [`GeoCoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class for this :

```
public String getAddress(double latitude, double longitude){

   if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
       try {
          Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
          List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);

          if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address first = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if(first.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0){
              sb.append(first.getAddressLine(0) + ", ");
            }

            sb.append(first.getLocality() + ", ");
            sb.append(first.getCountryName());

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("MyAPP", "Reverse geo lookup failed", e);
          return "Unavailable"
        }
    } else {
      return "unavailable";
    }
 }
```

Comment: thank u sir for you are valuable reply. but sir i dont know how to create or start service for geo coder will u please tell me ho to do that

Comment: @kirankirve No special service is required, that's just a method (see updated answer). This method may take some time to execute.

Comment: its worked thank u sir ..........when i create avd to google api then it work and return the address

Comment: hey one more query when i put this working code in working timer after every 5 min it make call to geo coder to return a address.in this activity geocoder throw exception array our of bound.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties > Android > set project build target to Google